# Using an SSD with my Macbook Pro, sometimes the write speed is downgraded to 10kb/s. Is it normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I am using a Samsung T5 500GB external SSD drive with my Macbook Pro, and when the drive is full, sometimes I move files to my other hard drives, and the "Info" already showed that the SSD drive had 12GB of free space.

However, when writing to the SSD drive, I found that it was limited to 10kb/s. After experimenting some more, I found that after I moved 2GB more away, then the write speed went back up to usual.

Could it be true that the SSD drive was internally arranging the segments so that there is more "evenly usage" so that it won't "age" the SSD too badly, so the write speed was limited to 10kb/s during this time or what reason may it be that the write speed dropped to so low?

P.S. I found that if I reboot the Macbook, the write speed of the SSD went back to normal for a while, and then dropped back to 10kb/s... so I wonder... what if I reboot the Macbook and let the SSD "do its job (of rearranging the segments)" for an hour or two and try again. Still exploring more.

Comment: Anecdotally - SSDs hate being full even more than HDs do. I've seen recommendations of up to 20% free space to let them 'breathe' properly.

Comment: @Tetsujin is there a reason for it? Supposedly, I think traditional HD, SSD, and Flash drives are just "a sea of 0s and 1s", kind of like, you give it "an address", then you can say set it to 0 or 1, or read it, and how you arrange the data, it is your choice (HFS, APFS, NTFS, exFAT). So by this same method of "SOP (standard operating procedure)", whether it is traditional HD, SSD, supposedly it should have no difference

Comment: Random Googled tutorial on the need to keep free space on drives - this one says 30% free space - https://pureinfotech.com/why-solid-state-drive-ssd-performance-slows-down/